# How to redirect to a different domain's url with post data

Tags: django, django-views

I have a single page application. First, the user posts JSON data (`amount` and `user` data) to the URL API on Django backend server (`Buy view`). Then the view gets the amount and user's data to create a hashed var. And finally, I want to redirect to a different domain's URL, which accepts the above data.

```
def Buy(request):
    key = 'some_key'
    txnid = 'some_id'
    amount = reques.data.get("amount")
    firstname = request.user.firstname
    surl = 'http://mysite.in/buy/success'
    furl = 'http://mysite.in/buy/fail'
    hash = ''
    salt = 'some_salt'
    hash_list = [key, txnid, str(amount), firstname, salt]
    hash_seq = "|".join(hash_list)
    hashed = hashlib.sha512(hash_seq)
    hashed_hexdigest_lower = hashed.hexdigest().lower()
    data = {
        "key": key,
        "txnid": txnid,
        "amount": amount,
        "firstname": firstname,
        "surl": surl,
        "furl": furl,
        "HASH": hashed_hexdigest_lower
    }
    url = "https://test.site.in/payment"
    return redirect(url, kwargs=data)
```

Basically, when the redirect happens, I want to post the above data to that URL like a form submission. How can I do this in Django?

Comment: what is the point of redirecting the user when its a post request redirect. just make a request with post data to the url https://test.site.in/payment on your server and whatever the response is you return it back to user

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes, that's the issue here. The URL (test.site.in/payment) is a different domain and not from my server. It's a payment gateway API of a different company that I am using.

Comment: use something like requests library to make a request to that other domain

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes, but I need to open that in the user's browser so that user can enter payment credentials. How can I do that using `requests`?

Comment: If user is entering his payment credentials then what are you trying to do by sending post request with user data to that server. If user is going to see that page then it should be a get request to the payment site which will show him the page.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki That is because the payment gate API requires a hashed key value pair which is created by the above data in the view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147693/discussion-between-arpit-solanki-and-kakar).

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Never mind, I think I now know how to solve this problem. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's SPA you save the data in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` and access from the new view after directing.

old view before redirecting,

```
localStorage.setItem('myData',data);
```

new view after redirecting,

```
var data = localStorage.getItem('myData');
localStorage.removeItem('myData');
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I guess you didn't understand my question. Actually, when the user posts (amount, name) to my URL api (`Buy view`), I will get that data (amount, name), and use it to create a hashed str. Finally, I want to redirect to different domain's URL which accepts a post request of the above data.

Comment: If your Application is an SPA and both the views are part of that SPA then I guess it's not possible. If the other view is not part of the SPA than you can probably send the data in the headers of the response for the new view.